# Transforming RDD[String] into RDD[Array[String]]

Tags: apache-spark

Given an `RDD{String]`, where each element on a line is delimited with the `|` character, for example:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd
```

What is the correct way to transform it into an `RDD[Array[String]`, so that the above would be represented as `Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")`

The following idea:

```
val rddAsArray = rdd.map { x => Array(x.split("""\|""")) }
```

does not apear to work.
as

```
println(rddAsArray.foreach { _.mkString(",") })
```

only prints: `[[Ljava.lang.String;@4096711f`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:

Try:

```
val rddAsArray = rdd.map(x => x.split("\\|"))
```

The way you were doing it you were creating an `RDD[Array[Array[String]]]` when all you want is `RDD[Array[String]]`.

And your `println` doesn't do what you think it does. Try:

```
rddAsArray.take(1).foreach(l => println(l.mkString(",")))
```

You need the `take()` to bring the `RDD` into your driver -- otherwise `println` will print its results to your executor's `stdout`, which you likely won't be able to see. You need it to print to your driver's `stdout`, hence the `take()`. And otherwise `println` needs to be nested within your `foreach`, not the other way around.